# java security configuration for ssl

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, digital-certificate

I have the following question on SSL/TLS.
After the server hello, starts the authentication phase of the server.
From various articles/books, it appears that this phase is optional. E.g. in wiki

> The server sends its Certificate
>   message (depending on the selected
>   cipher suite, this may be omitted by
>   the server).

But I do not understand what it means to say that it depends on the encryption suite.
So my understanding is either a `ServerKeyExchange` or a `Certificate` follows a `ServerHello`.
So my question is, can the server authentication be omitted all together?
For example to omit client aunthentication in Tomcat, you just configure the connector to not request it.
How can the server authentication be omitted? Does it depend on the java framework I use, if it supports it?
And what does it mean to omit the server authentication? If the certificate is not send then the `ServerKeyExchange` becomes mandatory, or usually frameworks allow provisioning of a local public key instead if one wants to by pass-authentication phase for performance or because it does not make any sense?
Or does this depends on the encryption suite somehow, as wiki seems to imply?
**NOTE:**
I understand that server should always be authenticated. The context of my problem though is a client app and server running on the same machine (and java runtime I guess) so it can be considered safe to bypass server authentication (I think).

Any input is highly welcome!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In TLS/SSL, server authentication is optional.
If you choose TLS/SSL cipher suite without authn (such as `TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL` (turns off authn and encryption) or `TLS_DH_anon_XXXX` (use only encryption) in TLS specification), server certificate won't be sent.

TLS/SSL without authn doesn't seem to be supported pure-Java connector.
But I think the native-connector with `SSLCipherSuite=aNULL` supports it.

I don't know it's safe to disable authn, i.e., attacks such as DNS-spoofing might be threats.
I think you'd better to use server authn if performance is not problem.
Or, turning off TLS/SSL itself might be choice.  (Encrypting server-client communication might be meaningless because administrator of the computer can steal certificate files and dump JVM heap.)

Comment: @habe:Thank you for the reply.So the non-authentication is possible only if the client supports anonymous DH?If not it is mandatory?That is the meaning in wiki quote?Also when you mention the native-connector, which class you are reffering?

Comment: @user384706: DH-anon support is requried for TLS w/o authn.  It's not mandatory in spec. (c.f. §9 of RFC 2246).  As “depending on the selected cipher suite” in Wikipedia, it should be same as what I say.  And native-connector is in http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/.

Comment: @habe:One last question:do you think dns spoofing could be a threat even when the client and server are in same machine?

Comment: @user384706: Yes.  When your client use “http://localhost:8080/” and DNS provides “localhost=<IP address other than 127.0.0.1>”, it might be redirected to another machine.

Comment: @habe:So there is no concept that I already have the public key store locally, I pass it to the java framework to use it and not ask it on authentication phase?Either DH anon is used or we have exchange of certificate?

Comment: @user384706: There are two options: First is to give up authn ,i.e., accept threats, and use DH-anon.  Second is to configure sending server cert to be authenticated.
Your idea (store server public key in client side to omit to send/receive it) might be possible if (1) server knows which client have server's pubkey and (2) client knows which pubkey corresponds to the server.  TLS/SSL does not have such a mapping functionality, so I think it's not possible in TLS/SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication and Encryption are important when data travels across an *untrusted* network or when one of the endpoints is not trusted.  If you application only makes connections on localhost, then Authentication and Encryption aren't important (the fact that your data and application are on locahost implies a trust in localhost).

Comment: What about DNS spoofing though?

Comment: "localhost" is in your hosts file; it won't use DNS and thus can't be spoofed.  Or use 127.0.0.1

Comment: Ok.But what if another name also is expected to resolve to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Won't happen. 127.*.*.* is a special range. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3330 , section 2, paragraph 6.  Habe's comment above is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

you can get ssl configuration for tomcat 6 from

http://nayanmali.blogspot.com/

you got whole configuration and how to create keytool and how to generate certificate form that